# Reference to figure is undefined

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a research paper and the issue that I am trying to resolve is related to referencing a figure. The warning in the editor says:

```
Reference fig:fig5 on page 2 undefined input
```

```
Now enter a title, Key Term 1, Description for Key Term 1, Key Term 2, and Description for Key Term 2. You can click the Add More button to create more entries for key terms and their descriptions. For example, to create the word matching exercise in Figure \ref{fig:fig5}, you can enter the following entries in Figure \ref{fig:fig5}.

Now click the Generate HTML button to display the generated HTML code for this word matching exercise. The HTML code is generated as shown in Figure \ref{fig:fig6}. Click the Post button to post the word match exercise to the server. 

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4, clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{figure/fig_4.PNG}
  \label{fig:fig5}
\end{figure}
```

The figure is labeled here:

```
\label{fig:fig5}
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The label must be inside the `\caption{}` or after it in the figure float. And of course, there must be a caption to reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That worked

```
Now enter a title, Key Term 1, Description for Key Term 1, Key Term 2, and Description for Key Term 2. You can click the Add More button to create more entries for key terms and their descriptions. For example, to create the word matching exercise in Figure \ref{fig:fig5}, you can enter the following entries in Figure \ref{fig:fig5}.

Now click the Generate HTML button to display the generated HTML code for this word matching exercise. The HTML code is generated as shown in Figure \ref{fig:fig6}. Click the Post button to post the word match exercise to the server. 

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4, clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{figure/fig_4.PNG}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:fig5}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: For anyone who is confused about what changed: An additional \caption{} was added.